# How to add .htaccess redirect to external domain with special characters

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

In my case when I try to redirect a URL with special characters automatically the special characters removed.
How to add a redirect in this case.

From URL

```
www.domain1.com/blog/test-blog
```

To URL

```
www.domain2.com/test%3a-test1%2a
```

This is my redirect code

```
RewriteRule ^blog/test-blog?$ https://domain1.com/test%3a-test1%2a [R=301,L]
```

But the special characters in the URL %3 and %2 got removed.

Comment: real address is `www.domain2.com/test:-test1*` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape `%` in target otherwise it is referenced as back-reference for capture groups in `RewriteCond`. Moreover you will have to `NE` flag to avoid escaping `%` in target URL.

```
RewriteRule ^blog/test-blog/?$ https://domain2.com/test\%3a-test1\%2a [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```

Comment: `RewriteRule /wp-content/uploads/test.pdf/?$ example.com/test.html [R=301,L]`

this is not working.

Comment: Is this rule not to be in root/.htaccess ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58742675/wordpress-how-to-redirect-files-under-wp-content-uploads-folder-to-another-domai